# Find outlook exchange profile creation date using VB

Tags: vba, outlook, ldap, exchange-server

My first question, so take it easy on me please, but constructive feedback on asking questions properly more than welcome

I program in a bespoke scripting language for a case management system, but occasionally need to step out to get other information. In the environment I am currently working in I have no admin rights and minimal server access.

I want to be able to pull exchange profile creation dates into the CMS to check users have been here over a year. I can’t work out the LDAP connection string, none of the power shell examples I have seen (dswuery, dsget etc) work and the only other method I can think that I have left to do this in is VB.

I assume I should be able to do this by getting a recipient and finding the creation date, but my attempts at this have been unsuccessful. Any pointers, tips, guidance or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: What profile? Local Outlook profile as seen in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles? Or the GAL user creation date?

Comment: I would be happy with either (truthfully on the basis that I don’t know the difference...) as I only want this date to check for a years employment in the business. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read PR_CREATION_TIME (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30070040`) from the `AddressEntry` object using `AddressEntry.PropetyAccessor.GetProperty`.

Fot the current (Outlook profile wise) user, `AddressEntry` can be retrieved from `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry`.